# Closed form of $\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^n}{\text{exp}(kz^m) - 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, power-series, analytic-number-theory

Recently while working on some problems, I came across this beautiful infinite series:

$$\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^n}{\text{exp}(kz^m) - 1}$$

where $m,n \in \mathbb{N} $. Does there exist a closed form for this infinite series? What happens if $m = n$? Can we find a closed form when $m = 2, n = 4?$ or when $m = 5, n=6$? What would be a general approach? Any idea? Can we use complex analytic methods such as residue theorem and stuff  to evaluate this series? I've been working on this infinite series from quite some time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $k$ a parameter too, or are you summing over $z$?

Comment: Why do you expect a closed form?  Any particular reasons?

Comment: @Mindlack Good question, I'm only summing over $z$. $k$ is just a constant

Comment: @Infinity_hunter I don't get what you exactly mean but I'm just wondering weather or not there exists a closed form (maybe not for general $m,n$ but for some specific values). I don't know, To be honest I have no idea that's why I've asked it on MSE. Thanks.

Comment: @pisco What's your approach for the values mentioned? It would be great if you could share it?

Comment: @Permutator  I would be extremely surprised if the series can be evaluated for any $m> 1$.

Comment: @pisco Can you please share on how you would deal with the case $m = 1$?

Comment: For m=1 it is probably worth noting that it is a Lambert series, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^s}{e^{\beta k}-1} =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_s(k)}{e^{\beta k}} $.

Comment: Deleting your question right after K posted an answer is very rude, @Permutator https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178520/evaluating-sum-k-mm-1k-e-fraci-pi-km-frac2-leftze-frac